# MySql Column Comparison MAtch

Tags: mysql

I have two columns in MySql where I would like to create a third column through a case statement to see if part of column A matches column B.  For example:

Column_A        Column_B                    Output
James A Smith   Smith/Associated/Walter     1
Elliot Rodgers  Julius Optimus/Etc          0

Something like

```
Case When Column_B like Column_A then 1
else 0 end) as Output
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: maybe use `Column_B LIKE CONCAT('%', Column_A, '%')`

Comment: It's currently returning only 0's.  For example I have one column where Column_A = Joe Smith and Column_B = Smith Joe and it is flagging that as  a 0 when it should be a 1.

Comment: Your are asking if a work  in the first columns sentence matc with  word of the second column sentence?

Comment: Concat isn't working either.  It is still throwing a 0 for all observations, thanks.

Comment: I am asking if any of the words match in A to B so if Smith is in A and is in any part of B then to count that as a match.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of words that would be in either column?

Comment: There isn't a limit.  So if one of the words in column A appears anywhere in column B then it would be considered a match